# Is there possibility in hawkbit update devices by MAC address?

Tags: eclipse-hawkbit

Is there possibility in havkbit tup different groups of devices based on MAC adress ?

For example if i need to update some devices and other dos not update

I didnot find that option in UI of hawkbit

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a target filter with the MAC address pattern (e.g. `attribute.mac_address==CA:FE:*` would create a target group of devices that have MAC addresses starting with "CA:FE:"). The only caveat I believe is that you need to have the MAC address populated in the attributes for each of those devices.  See https://www.eclipse.org/hawkbit/apis/mgmt/targetfilters/ for how you can also create these via API